# Java Webstart attempt to sandboxed jar as "Trusted-Library"

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I'm trying to load a signed jar with an unsigned library through Webstart. However I get a "attempt to open sandboxed jar as Trusted-Library" error. I removed the all permissions setting from my jnlp file, if let it there (which I prefer not to), I get a classnotdefined exception for my library.
I'm using Netbeans to sign my jar with Trusted Library setting.
Would it work if I signed the library (which is not mine, but GPL'ed)?

All is working locally, btw, just not from Webstart.
Thanks,
Kaj

**The manifest file:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Trusted-Library: true
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Class-Path: lib/tools.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0-b147 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: customcompile.CustomCompile

Name: customcompile/Source.class
SHA-256-Digest: WFa1FC4Q07sE3S9XxmUSEpgUKjvjYo81urGSiiLNBYY=

Name: customcompile/Output.class
SHA-256-Digest: Sc8oRhAcYYrEtWY5iA56bNKx4EuHQHgFfHmXRSYV474=

Name: customcompile/CustomCompile.class
SHA-256-Digest: WYmy6ny6BU6sYFqJCwxSUPsbTWbpvBuPurYuwnZR5sM=

Name: customcompile/MemoryClassLoader.class
SHA-256-Digest: 0bUNmC+gI7dkGFzEmDvAqdOv15UmHOQS8dDVi9FxGFU=

Name: META-INF/INDEX.LIST
SHA-256-Digest: komZP7Un7Uyi8XTq+HvpbZtNF5cfPC8TmGiPBfcO3qk=

Name: customcompile/MemoryFileManager.class
SHA-256-Digest: GorTXt3N3GZ2kUHry7qBfAOgUuYvhWHE3S+SGEjzR7k=
```

I found some info on the subject as well ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html ):
at the bottom one finds a Q&A about mixed code, suggesting setting a lazy mode on the library, which did not do anything for me.

Comment: Is this a publicly accessible .JNLP? If so, can you include the URL for testing?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .jar's manifest file in your original question?

Comment: Done, there's not much info in it though.

Comment: This manifest is probably what NetBeans is showing you, but that's not the actual manifest file from the JAR file AFTER it's built. Can you grab that Manifest file and post its contents? The clue that you've got the right one is that it WILL have the main class listed (as opposed to `Main-Class will be added automatically by build`)

Comment: Sorry about that, updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find answers in [Mixing Signed and Unsigned Code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html).  See especially [Deploying Signed Applications and Applets Securely Without a Mixed Code Warning](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest).

---

Note that manifest above has..

```
..
Trusted-Library: true
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Trusted-Only: true
..
```

It should be one or the other of `Trusted-Library` or `Trusted-Only` (AFAIU).  In this case it should be `Trusted-Library`.

Comment: Can I simply remove the Trusted-Only line from the manifest.mf file? Note that I simply told Netbeans to use the Trusted-Library mode at Properties > Webstart > Customize.

Comment: I changed to Trusted-Library (I had to clean and build for this), and this changed the error to attempt to sandboxed jar CustomCompile.jar as "Trusted-Library"

Comment: What if you take out both lines? Does it just completely break?

Comment: It works if I run the webstart jnlp locally, but not from the url: http://kalpha.com/test/launch.jnlp. I must note as well, I'm creating a classloader, which seems to cause trouble with Webstart I read. However this happens in the signed jar.

Comment: I forgot I signed the library, trying an unsigned on now.

Comment: And that works! Great! Dont know why I didnt come across it myself.

Comment: I got the classnotdefined error maybe because I did not reupload the library, even though I used the exact same library, it is being picky on this point.