# Security Exception: Attempted to to open a sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Library

Tags: java, security, jar, jogl

I'm trying to run an applet via a webpage but doing so gives me the error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargeException
       at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(DeployAWTUtil.java:116)
       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Plugin2Manager.java:3520)
       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3051)
       at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by:java.lang.SecurityExcption: attempted to open sandboxed jar file :/home/daniel/workspace/project/jars/jogl/jogl.all.jar as a Trusted-Library
       at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandlers$ParentElement.checkResources(CPCallbackHandler.java:358)
       at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(DeployURLClassPath:852)
       ....more stuff I don't want to have to retype but I can if necessary
```

and I don't understand why. I'm trying to get at several jars with my applet but this is the only one that's causing the problem (at least for the moment). I looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093935/java-webstart-attempt-to-sandboxed-jar-as-trusted-library), but since I don't have an extra library (unless the applet.class counts which I haven't signed anyway), this doesn't seem to apply here. I looked at [Mixing Signed and Unsigned Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest), but "Enable - show warning if needed" is clicked, "Trusted-Library: true" is in the MANAFEST file, and I'm running firefox 3.6.24 (as specific for a Linux machine which I have). I'd appreciated your help.

jogl.all.jar's MANAFEST file:

```
Manifer-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_24-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Specification-Title: Java Bindings for OpenGL API Specification
Specification-Version: 2.0
Specificaiton-Vender: JogAMp Community
Implementation-Title: Java Bindings for OpenGL Runtime Environment
Implementation-Version: 2.0-b23-20110303
Implementation-Branch: rc
Implementation-Commit: bcf5d6ac871a29398b441df617923d3dd2cf35c1
Implementation-Vendor: JogAmp Community
Implementation-URL: http://jogamo.org/
Extension-Name: javax.media.opengl
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.jogamp
Trusted-Library: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you have not signed the jar (hence the "sandboxed" bit).

Writing trusted Java code that can safely be used by untrusted code is *really*, *really* difficult.

Comment: are you talking about the jogl.all.jar? I didn't write that so I'm no supposed to sign it, right? or am I incorrect and signing is independent of who wrote/published it?

Comment: @Daniel Tricky question. Anyone can sign anything. What are the right and proper things to sign is another question. I think you should be able to find versions of JOGL marked as a Trusted-Library that are signed and possibly maintained (it wont be by Sun anymore).

Comment: If you sign something yourself (any jar file for the for the sake of learning), does that allow you to avoid this issue I'm having? or do must you go find a "trusted-Library" version?

Comment: @Daniel You can sign any jar including trusted-libraries with any [code signing] certificate. I suggest avoiding using real certificates signed by CAs for testing.

Comment: I've not tried it, but wouldn't it also work to put the sand-boxed code into a JNLP extension that is sand-boxed, and reference that extension in the main JNLP?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It shouldn't be possible to have applets/JNLP load trusted and untrusted code through the same class loader (unless you write some trusted code to do that, of course, and then you're on your own). If you find a way around that, please e-mail secalert_us. To put trusted and untrusted code together, the way to go is to have use safely written trusted-library. I guess you could use two applets (in different contexts) or webstart applications.

Comment: Signed the third party JARs as well as added `Trusted-Library: true` to their manifests. I was using with my signed applet JAR, and it got rid of this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue - the root cause was Java JRE installed as both 32bit and 64bit versions - basically there were 2 separate app entries visible in the "Control Panel/Add or remove programs" list.

Apparently this was confisung my web browser (IE) and/or java plugin. Removing both JRE versions from the system, then installing the latest JRE from scratch solved the problem.

My issue was seen on Java 7u25.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to JRE version, try to use by .01 lower version or higher version.